# How to get data from json file in angularjs 2

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs2. I have to retrieve data from json file to a array. So that I can use json data in my components.Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? What have you tried? Stack Overflow is not a place to ask for tutorials. Please share code to show your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to keep your json file in src/assets folder and read from there with http

```
getFromFile(){
  debugger;
  return this.http.get("./assets/data.json")
    .map((response: Response) =>response.json())
    .catch(this._errorHandler);
}
_errorHandler(error:Response){
  console.log(error);
  return Observable.throw(error || "Internal server error");
}
```

You will need to import these:

```
  import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
  import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
  import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
```